# How do I tether 2 stepper driver boards on a Panucat X5 GT with 2660 Bigfoot Drivers (2 motors to drive 1 axis)

Tags: cnc

I have a panucatt X5 GT board running smoothieware and I am trying to make 2 stepper motors work synchronously to move the X axis.

It seems like it could be done via software pins but I have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: and your question is....??

Comment: Please share your code that you have and what exactly isn't working so that people can help.